# Variable inaccessible to JS when in partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a signup form with JS validation. It works fine when the signup form is directly in the html. However, when the signup form is accessed via a partial, it fails to read the variables from the form. In that case the form always displays the error 'Please type in your name.'

JS:

```
$('.js-sign-up-submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    var nameFirst = $('.js-user-name-first').val();
    if (!nameFirst) {
      $('.js-sign-up-error').text('Please type in your name.');
    }
    ...
});
```

html layout:

```
<body>
  <%= render :partial => "/shared/header" %>
  <% if notice %>
    <p class="alert alert-notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
    <p class="alert alert-error"><%= alert %></p>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render :partial => "/shared/login_form" %>
  <%= render :partial => "/shared/sign_up_form" %>
  <%= render :partial => "/shared/password_reset_form" %>
  <%= render :partial => "/shared/footer" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "home" %>

</body>
```

Comment: Is your JS within a `document.ready()` callback?

Comment: from bug description, click event is handled, so callback in right place

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the partial for the signup form was called in two places: in the layout file (as shown above) AND in the shared header file. So the JS was validating the signup form linked to in the layout which was not the one filled out by the user, hence failing to register the inputted text. We simply removed the duplicate signup partial in the header and it now works fine.